# footer goes down on adding dynamic list element

Tags: jquery, html

When ever I am adding some list element to my list the footer goes down in my html page.
after that when I click on page(anywhere on page) footer comes its original position.

I want to ask what to do for placing footer to its original position(sticking at bootom of screen) after adding dynamic list element.

code for adding fixed footer:

```
<div id='ref_fot' data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar">
        <a href="#create_task" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-right" style="float:right;margin-right:20px;border-radius:6px;">Add Task</a>
        </div>
```

adding list element dynamically:

```
 $("#list").append('<li><a href="#Display_task" class="ui-link-inherit" data-icon="home">'+obj.title+'</a></li>');
      $("#list").listview ("refresh");
```

Comment: add a class to your footer div. Then in css rules put `position:fixed`

Comment: Code for footer: <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar"> and code for adding list element: $("#list").append('<li><a href="#create_task" class="ui-link-inherit" data-icon="home">'+obj.title+'</a></li>');

Comment: I have fixed footer but whenever list element is added is goes down.on double clicking on the page it comes to its orignal position.

Comment: @ShobhaSingh if possible then make a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link, so that everyone easily view that what you have done, and easily modified by others..